# What is the (# ... #) syntax seen in F# standard library implementation?

Tags: f#, cil

Reading sources of Array2D module, I've stumbled upon this interesting construct in implementation of many core functions, for example:

```
[<CompiledName("Get")>]
let get (array: 'T[,]) (n:int) (m:int) =  (# "ldelem.multi 2 !0" type ('T) array n m : 'T #)
```

I can only assume that this is the syntax to inline CIL and is used here obviously to gain performance benefits. However, when I've tried to use this syntax in my program, I get an error:

```
warning FS0042: This construct is deprecated: it is only for use in the F# library
```

What exactly is this? Is there any detailed documentation?

Comment: *looks like a puzzled face to me*

Comment: I understand curiosity but I'd take the warning that it's only for use in the F# library as a sign that it's nothing that any of us need to use :-)

Comment: You might want to post what you found as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: Cool, I've edited the question and moved that part to an answer.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'd like to ignore it, but the simple reality is F# IntelliSense says some of my let expressions have this type.  It seems to happen when I write: `let (a, b, c) = ...`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that this has 2 purposes:

1. These functions compile down to exactly 1 CIL instruction which has to be encoded somewhere, so encoding at the source seems best.
2. It allows for some extra trickery with defining polymorphic `Add` functions in a high performance way which is hard with the F# type system.

You can actually use this but you have to specify the `--compiling-fslib` (undocumented) and `--standalone` flags in your code.

Comment: Great! Where did you find about those compiler options?

Comment: @e-i-s - There is a source file which has them all somewhere - not quite sure where though - searching the source for `standalone` will probably help

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why some VS2019 IntelliSense inferred type signatures have `(#a -> unit) * float * SomeType list)` - apologies if I'm missing something I should infer from the answer.

Comment: I think I figured it out - #a is a Flexible Type - accepts any subtype of a.

Answer (score 9):

I've found some details in usenet archives: http://osdir.com/ml/lang.fsharp.general/2008-01/msg00009.html

> > Embedded IL in F# codes. Is this feature officially supported
>
> Not really. The 99.9% purpose of this feature is for operations defined
>   in FSharp.Core.dll (called fslib.dll in 1.9.2.9 and before).
>
> Historically it has been useful to allow end-users to embed IL in order
>   to access .NET IL functionality not accessible by F# library or
>   language constructs using their own embedded IL. The need for this is
>   becoming much more rare, indeed almost non-existent, now that the F#
>   library has matured a bit more. We expect this to continue to be the
>   case. It's even possible that we will make this a library-only feature
>   in the "product" version of F#, though we have not yet made a final
>   decision in this regard.

This was a message from Don Syme, dated January of 2008.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why some VS2019 IntelliSense inferred type signatures have `(#a -> unit) * float * SomeType list)` - apologies if I'm missing something I should infer from the answer.

Comment: I think I figured it out - #a is a Flexible Type - accepts any subtype of a.