# Calling `zeroCreateUnchecked` from an F# program

Tags: f#

I can see in the FSharp.Core source code, that their library functions often call `Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked count` to create a zero initialized array.  In order to do some performance comparisons with the core libraries I would like to do the same, but it is a private method that I can't seem to access. I can see the definition of the function is:

```
let inline zeroCreateUnchecked (count:int) =        
    (# "newarr !0" type ('T) count : 'T array #)
```

But that doesn't appear to be valid in a normal F# program either. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: That's a secret/deprecated way of inlining IL in F# code, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968054/what-is-the-syntax-seen-in-f-standard-library-implementation

Comment: Thank you, that link is perfect.